# Testing for a shortcode using a function. 404 page throwing PHP Notice

Tags: functions, shortcode, 404-error, conditional-tags

I'm using the following function (can't remember where I found it, but I think it was written by pippin so thanks to him) to test for a shortcode.

```
function has_shortcode($shortcode = '') {

   $post_to_check = get_post( get_the_ID() );

   // false because we have to search through the post content first
   $found = false;

   // if no short code was provided, return false
   if ( !$shortcode ) {
      return $found;
   }

   if (  stripos( $post_to_check->post_content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {
      // we have found the short code
      $found = true;
   }

   // return our final results
   return $found;
}
```

The problem is, on a page such as a 404 page I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/post-template.php on line 30
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme-functions.php on line 49
```

On theme-functions in line 49 is this line from the above function

```
if (  stripos( $post_to_check->post_content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {
```

If I remove the function call **if( has_shortcode('gallery') )** ... from another file, the two errors go away. I believe the two are related and if I fix the function it will clear them both. I can "kind of" understand why this is happening... my understanding is that on the 404 page there is no $post variable set so somehow I need to modify the function to test first. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function has_shortcode($shortcode = '') {
  global $post;
 // false because we have to search through the post content first
 $found = false;

 // if no short code was provided, return false
 if ( !$shortcode ) {
    return $found;
 }

 if (  is_object( $post ) && stripos( $post->post_content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {
     // we have found the short code
  $found = true;
 }

// return our final results
return $found;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has removed the notices and everything still works as expected.